# How can I save 3 different values in MySQL DB without using an integer?

Tags: mysql

I want to save 3 different values for an online shopping site (buying, selling, borrowing). 
Is there a dedicated data-type more efficent than integer ?

Comment: There is ENUM, but it's advised not to use it. There other integer typer like tinyint which can go from 0 to 255 I believe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649126/mysql-tri-state-field

Comment: Just use an `INT` column. You can use `TINYINT` but I really doubt you'll ever notice the difference. You can probably get away with using a `VARCHAR(255)` column with the action spelled out as text unless you're dealing with tens of thousands of transactions per second.